# How do I correctly implement std::iter::Step in Rust 1.25 nightly?

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a struct to represent a date, which can be used with range syntax (`for d in start..end { }`).  I know there are already crates out there that handle dates, but I am doing this as an exercise.

Here is the struct:

```
type DayOfMonth = u8;
type Month = u8;
type Year = u16;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone)]
pub struct Date {
    pub year: Year,
    pub month: Month,
    pub day: DayOfMonth
}
```

Here is how I would like to use it:

```
fn print_dates() {
    let start = Date { year: 1999, month: 1, day: 1 };
    let end = Date { year: 1999, month: 12, day: 31 };

    for d in start..end {
        println!("{}-{}-{}", d.year, d.month, d.day);
    }
}
```

I originally tried implementing the `Iterator` trait, but then when I tried to use range syntax, I got a compiler error saying I needed to implement `Step` instead.

The documentation shows this signature for the `Step` trait.

```
pub trait Step: PartialOrd<Self> + Clone {
    fn steps_between(start: &Self, end: &Self) -> Option<usize>;
    fn replace_one(&mut self) -> Self;
    fn replace_zero(&mut self) -> Self;
    fn add_one(&self) -> Self;
    fn sub_one(&self) -> Self;
    fn add_usize(&self, n: usize) -> Option<Self>;
}
```

I've already implemented `Ord` and `PartialOrd`:

```
impl Ord for Date {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
         match self.year.cmp(&other.year) {
            Ordering::Equal =>
                match self.month.cmp(&other.month) {
                    Ordering::Equal =>
                        self.day.cmp(&other.day),
                    ord => ord
                },
            ord => ord
        }
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Date {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}
```

I am implementing `Clone` automatically with `#[derive(Clone)]`.

I started implementing `Step`, but there are some methods that I cannot figure out what to do with.  Here is what I have so far:

```
impl Step for Date {
    fn steps_between(start: &self, end: &self) -> Option<usize> {
        //is_valid_date checks that the month is not > 12 and other rules like that
        if is_valid_date(start) && is_valid_date(end) {
            //get_epoch_day_number gets the number of days since 1900-01-01
            let diff = get_epoch_day_number(end) - get_epoch_day_number(start);
            Some(diff)
        }
        else { None }
    }

    fn add_one(&self) -> Self {
        //Try the next day
        let mut next = Date {
            year: self.year,
            month: self.month,
            day: self.day + 1
        };
        //If not valid, try the 1st of the next month
        if !is_valid_date(&next) {
            next = Date {
                year: self.year,
                month: self.month + 1,
                day: 1
            };
        }
        //If not valid, try the 1st of the next year
        if !is_valid_date(&next) { 
            next = Date {
                year: self.year + 1,
                month: 1,
                day: 1
            };
        }
        next
    }

    fn sub_one(&self) -> Self {
        //Try the prev day
        let mut prev = Date {
            year: self.year,
            month: self.month,
            day: self.day - 1
        };
        //If not valid, try the last of the prev month
        if !is_valid_date(&prev) {
            let m = self.month - 1;
            prev = Date {
                year: self.year,
                month: m,
                day: get_month_length(self.year, m)
            };
        }
        //If not valid, try the last of the prev year
        if !is_valid_date(&prev) {             
            prev = Date {
                year: self.year - 1,
                month: 12,
                day: 31
            };
        }
        prev
    }

    fn add_usize(&self, n: usize) -> Self {
        //This is really inefficient, but that's not important
        let mut result = self;
        for i in 1..n+1 {
            result = result.add_one();
        }
        result
    }

    fn replace_one(&mut self) -> Self {
        // ?
    }

    fn replace_zero(&mut self) -> Self {
        // ?
    }
}
```

I am really stumped on what `replace_one` and `replace_zero` are supposed to do.  The documentation says:

*Replaces this step with `1`, returning itself.* and *Replaces this step with `0`, returning itself.*

Does my struct need to have `zero` and `one` identity values just to be used in a range?  Shouldn't `add_one` be enough?

The wording used by the documentation is also a little unclear.  If we replace `x` with `1` and return "itself", is "it" `x` or `1`?

Comment: The question isn't bad, but I wouldn't recommend implementing `Step` at this point in time. It's probably simpler to implement `Date::range_to(Date)` which returns a new struct which implements `Iterator`.

Comment: Just a generic hint: it's usually best to make sure values are always "valid".  This means you should make fields private if they could contain invalid values, and you should provide a constructor that can fail: `pub fn new(...) -> Option<Date>`. `is_valid_date` should be private and only be called when you create new values internally to make sure you only return valid values.

Answer (score 2):

I just looked at Rust's code where those methods are used. [The only uses in whole of rustc's repository](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/0c6091fbd0eee290c651f73be899f221eeab3c05/src/libcore/iter/range.rs#L342) are to implement `RangeInclusive` operations. An empty `RangeInclusive` is represented as a range from `1` to `0`, so the `next`, `next_back` and `nth` methods need to be able to get those somehow, and that's what `replace_one` and `replace_zero` are for.

I would suggest opening an issue on rustc's GitHub to make the documentation better, and possibly change the name of these methods.

Comment: Maybe elaborate why those are needed: `RangeInclusive` returns an item as long as `start <= end`, and advances `start` after each run.  But if `end` is the maximum value that can be represented, you cannot reach `start == end + 1` - so instead, if `start == end` it replaces `start` and `end` with some abstract values named `one` and `zero` which need to fulfill `zero < one` so the loop stops. Apart from that it should not matter which values you choose to return.